# mySQL SELECT DISTINCT not working

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have tried and tried but can't figure this one out. I'm using a chained series of select menus, pulling options from a mySQL database. The chaining all works well and everything works great except i only want to return distinct values for the transmission types and fuel types.

Here's my current query:

```
<?php 
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX')
or die('Cannot connect to db');

$result = $conn->query("select id, model_id, gearbox from derivatives ORDER BY gearbox ASC");

    echo '<select name="gearbox" id="gearbox">';
    echo '<option value="" selected>Please Choose ...</option>';

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $modelid = $row['model_id'];
        $gearbox = $row['gearbox'];
        echo '<option class="'.$modelid.'">'.$gearbox.'</option>';
    };

    echo "</select>";
?>
```

This output the following select menu:

```
Automatic
Automatic
Automatic
Automatic
Automatic
Manual
```

Whereas i would like for it to only show the two options available:

```
Automatic
Manual
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have tried using `SELECT DISTINCT` but had no joy

Comment: *"SELECT DISTINCT but had no joy"* - You should post what you did try. Add a GROUP BY to that also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you only care about unique gearbox values you can do:

`SELECT DISTINCT gearbox from derivatives ORDER BY gearbox ASC`

This will not get you the `id` and `model_id` fields, but since you only want to display the gearbox...

`SELECT gearbox from derivatives GROUP BY gearbox` will also get the job done, and you can return additional aggregate fields with it ( add `max(id)` or `min(model_id)` for example).

Comment: Thanks Paqash. That's what i was thinking however it breaks the chaining as i need to pull in the other columns as classes. How would i rewrite the query, using both your comments and bringing in all the column data i need?

Comment: if there are 5 rows that have automatic gearbox, which id and model_id do you want? do you even care?

Comment: If you don't care, you can just add max(id) and max(model_id) .. if you care, you need to have more logic - which is it

Comment: I don't care which ones - i just want a maxmimum of 1 option for each. So instead of 5 automatics and 2 manuals. I just want 1 automatic and 1 manual. Thanks for this!

Comment: ok so just `SELECT max(id) as id, max(model_id) as model_id, gearbox from derivatives GROUP BY gearbox`

Comment: That's pulling no results in now. How can something so simple be so tricky, ha! Thanks for your help though!

Comment: That's not actually possible :)

Comment: Thanks for that. I guess your code must be right - but the grouping is breaking the chaining somehow. Thanks for your help!